# HTML/JS - Background video. Autoplay a random video after the next one ends?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm creating a page where I have a list of 16 video's which I want to play at random each time the page loads. That works fine, but it will keep looping the current loaded video and not pick another random video. I did include an event listener when the video ends but it's not really doing anything.

HTML

```
<div class="video-container">
    <video playsinline loop id ="intro" autoplay id="intro" muted></video>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var videos = [
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/1.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/2.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/3.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/4.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/5.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/6.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/7.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/8.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./meida/9.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/10.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/11.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/12.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/13.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/14.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/15.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'./media/16.mp4'}],
];

var randomitem = videos[Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length)];

function videoadd(element, src, type) {
    var source = document.createElement('source');
    source.src = src;
    source.type = type;
    element.appendChild(source);
}

function newvideo(src) {
    var vid = document.getElementById("intro");
    videoadd(vid,src ,'video/mp4');
    vid.autoplay = true;
    vid.load();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    newvideo(randomitem[0].src)

    document.getElementById('intro').addEventListener('ended', myHandler,false);
    
    function myHandler(e) {
        newvideo(randomitem[0].src)
    }
})
```

I tried the video end event listener in the html with

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('intro').addEventListener('ended', myHandler,false);
    
    function myHandler(e) {
        newvideo(randomitem[0].src)
    }
</script>
```

I tried to implement it into the javascript itself but the function returned (e) is declared but it's value is never read.

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle the array and call the videos in order from that.

```js
let i = 0;
const randomVideos = videos
randomVideos.sort(() => (Math.random() > .5) ? 1 : -1); //shuffle

...

function myHandler(e) {
        newvideo(randomVideos[++i][0].src);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with the onEnded event, instead of using add event listener :

```
 var backgroundVideo = document.getElementById('intro');
     backgroundVideo.onended = () => {
     //here you can change the src atribute to change the video and play it again
}
```

Comment: This does not change anything. `element.onended = handler` and `element.addEventListener('ended', handler)` do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by listening for the ended event on the video, and selecting a new random video when that fires.
It would look something like this:

```
videoElement.addEventListener('ended', () => {
  // Select and play a new random video here
});
```

So in your code, you would add that listener in your $(document).ready handler:

```
document.getElementById('intro').addEventListener('ended', () => {
  newvideo(randomitem[0].src);
});
```

That will play a new random video each time the current one ends.

Comment: This will play the same video again becuase randomIitem[0] stays the same.

Comment: You're absolutely right! To play a random video each time, you need to recalculate randomItem inside the ended handler. It could look like this:
`function myHandler(e) {
    randomitem = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];
    newvideo(randomitem[0].src);
}`

This will choose a new random video from the videos array each time a video ends, and play that one.

Comment: Mind sharing the whole code? I tried to implement your code snippet, but it's still looping the same one 

`
$(document).ready(function(){
    newvideo(randomitem[0].src)

    document.getElementById('intro').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);

    function myHandler(e) {     
        randomitem = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];     
        newvideo(randomitem[0].src); 
    }
})
`

Comment: You're not updating randomItem inside myHandler, you're just re-using the initial random value you generated on page load.
Add this line:
`randomitem = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];`

...as the first line of myHandler, and it should work.
Side note: I'd strongly recommend not using a global variable for randomItem. Keep it scoped to myHandler instead.

Comment: It's still looping the same one it selected on page load. I currently have     
`
function myHandler(e) {     
        randomitem = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];     
        newvideo(randomitem[0].src); 
    }
`

Sidenote: It's still giving me 'e' is declared but its value is never read. ts(6133)

Comment: The event handler is expecting an Event object as its argument, but you've declared it as e. TypeScript is smart enough to know that you're not using e, so it gives you that error and omits the argument entirely from the generated JavaScript.
So in JavaScript, myHandler is being called with no arguments, but you're using e as if it were an Event.
The fix is simple: add the expected type:
`function myHandler(e: Event) {
    // ...
}`

Now TypeScript will generate the argument, and your code will work.

Comment: Unfortunately the code doesn't work. using e: Event will completely break the videoplayer entirely and won't output anything, changing it back to e will make it work again, but stop the video once it's over. Also I'm pretty sure I'm doing pure JS, not typescript. Not sure why my code editor does that.

Comment: `function myHandler(e) {
    randomitem = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];
    newvideo(randomitem[0].src);
}
`
This should be working if the newvideo is correctly working, you can check this by passing any other id other than the one which is loaded on the start to check if it's working
Typescript warning should have to do anything with it in the first palace.

Comment: It looks like the handler(e) does work fine, and it's the randomvideo that's not doing anything. I did the same what I do with Lua passing a print to make sure an event or trigger fires and I passed an Alert() in the myHandler and the alert pops, but the next video doesn't play. So the issue is lying there.